# understanding require() with module.exports with javascript and browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I am a c++ programmer at heart and I'm currently being thrown into the deep end with javascript and asked to swim very quick. I am using browserify so I am able to use the require function that node.js uses to get get access to code in other files. Now everything I have done seems to be working fine, I am just unsure that I am doing it correctly.

```
//a.js
module.exports = function(){
    alert("hello world");
}

//b.js
var myClass = new MyClass();
module.exports = myClass;

//c.js
var a = require("./a.js");
a();
var b = require(./b.js");
b.prototype.test = 555;

//d.js
function () {
    var a = require("./a.js");
    a();
    var b = require(./b.js");
    assert(b.test === 555);
}
function () { // duplicated require called inside same file but different function
    var a = require("./a.js");
    a();
}
```

So in every function and every file I want to use a.js do I have to put the require call? Seems like it will get a bit convoluted. Is there a better way to do this? Also assuming that c.js is ran before d.js will the assert pass or does it result in a copy being created of myClass so the objects are different between C and D?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "Seems like it will get a bit convoluted" --- so `#include` and linking is fine, but `require` is convoluted. How so?

Comment: Looking at minmaxavg post below he has shown that I was using require incorrectly. The fact that you assign it to a variable confused me so I was using it in the same file in multiple functions. So by putting it once at the top just like #include solves that for me. It isn't convoluted, just my understanding was wrong. Hence the post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `require` function is cached, so it would be the same **only within a single process**.

By the way, I cannot understand why you `require` `a.js` twice. Why not just do

```
//d.js
var a = require("./a.js");
function () {
    a();
    var b = require("./b.js");
    assert(b.test === 555); // success!
}
function () { // no dupes!
    a();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't putting it at the top as I got confused regarding assigning require to a variable and didn't consider it. Thanks again

Comment: @codetemplar You're welcome! Is it okay to ask you to mark the answer as accepted (the button below the vote down button) if you find it helpful?